# userns-remap option in Docker Swarm (existing) installation

Tags: linux, docker

I decided to increase security by enabling *userns-remap* option in Docker running in swarm mode.

Installation is not new, there's plenty of running services.

Followed configuration with official manual: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/

Docker service is starting but *docker service ls* throws error:

> Handler for GET /v1.40/services returned error: This node is not a swarm manager. Use docker swarm init or docker swarm join to connect this node to swarm and try again
>
> Error getting services: This node is not a swarm manager. Use docker swarm init or docker swarm join to connect this node to swarm and try again

*cat /etc/docker/daemon.json* is simple as

```
{
  "userns-remap": "default"
}
```

*cat /etc/subuid /etc/subgid*

```
dockremap:100000:65536
dockremap:100000:65536
```

*id dockremap*

```
uid=1000(dockremap) gid=1000(dockremap) groups=1000(dockremap)
```

*ls -ld /var/lib/docker/100000.100000/*

```
drwx------ 11 231072 231072 26 Mar 21 20:19 /var/lib/docker/100000.100000/
```

Removing *userns-remap* from config brings services back to normal.

Running CentOS 7.7 and docker 19.03.8

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/:

> Enabling userns-remap effectively masks existing image and container
>   layers, as well as other Docker objects within /var/lib/docker/. This
>   is because Docker needs to adjust the ownership of these resources and
>   actually stores them in a subdirectory within /var/lib/docker/. It is
>   best to enable this feature on a new Docker installation rather than
>   an existing one.

Ergo - all existing images and containers will not be available after enabling user namespace.